# How to define which property ListView should use to render

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I have a java bean object list which I would like to display in ListView control. By default ListView uses toString method.

How can I define which property to use for rendering in ListView?

I want to achieve same functionality as in TableView can be achieved by PropertyValueFactory in this code:

```
@FXML
private TableView<Person> mainTableView;
//...
TableColumn<Person,String> personColumn = new TableColumn<>("Name");List
personColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("name"));
mainTableView.getColumns().add(personColumn);
```

**Edit**

It looks like there is no easy(out of the box) solution. Based on code from James_D I created generic class to deal with the problem. It wraps PropertyValueFactory - note that PropertyValueFactory firstly looks for method [NAME]Property() trying to get observable, only when it is not found it tries to access standard bean properties.

```
public class PropertyValueFactoryWrapperCellFactory<T> implements Callback<ListView<T>, ListCell<T>> {

    private final PropertyValueFactory<T, String> pvf;

    public PropertyValueFactoryWrapperCellFactory(String propertyName) {
        super();
        pvf = new PropertyValueFactory(propertyName);
    }

    @Override
    public ListCell<T> call(ListView<T> param) {
        return new ListCell<T>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                textProperty().unbind();
                if (item == null) {
                    return;
                }
                TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<T, String> cdf = new TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<>(null, null, item);
                textProperty().bind(pvf.call(cdf));
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
@FXML
private ListView<Person> mainListView;
//...
mainListView.setCellFactory(new PropertyValueFactoryWrapperCellFactory("name"));
```

Comment: Why don't you override the toString method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a cell factory.

If the property is immutable, it's pretty straightforward:

```
ListView<MyDataType> listView = new ListView<>();
listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<MyDataType>, ListCell<MyDataType>>() {
    @Override
    public ListCell<MyDataType> call(ListView<MyDataType> lv) {
        return new ListCell<MyDataType>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(MyDataType item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item == null) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    // assume MyDataType.getSomeProperty() returns a string
                    setText(item.getSomeProperty());
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
```

If the property can change its value and the list view needs to update dynamically in response to these changes, you need to bind the `textProperty` of the list cell:

```
listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<MyDataType>, ListCell<MyDataType>>() {
    @Override
    public ListCell<MyDataType> call(ListView<MyDataType> lv) {
        return new ListCell<MyDataType>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(MyDataType item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                textProperty().unbind();
                if (item == null) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    // assumes MyDataType.someProperty() returns a StringProperty:
                    textProperty.bind(item.someProperty());
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### Binding String Property

This code allows you to choose what JavaFX property is displayed in a ListView. I use an anonymous class inside a lambda to add some clarity to what is happening. In this example:

- **Display** - The underlying object behind the ListView
- **titleProperty** - The JavaFX property to be displayed

```
listView.setCellFactory( 
    listview -> { 
        return new ListCell<Display>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Display item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                textProperty().unbind();
                if(item != null)
                    textProperty().bind(item.titleProperty());
                else
                    setText(null);
            }
        };
    }
);
```

### Explanation

With this code, we are basically making a custom ListCell. When it is updated and the item it is display is `null`, we clear the display text. Otherwise, we set the text to be whatever the title property of our item is.

---

#### TL;DR :: Modified James_D's Solution

I based this on James_D's second example. I wanted to bind a `SimpleStringProperty` to be the displayed text in a ListView. James_D's solution worked great but didn't update when I deleted an object from the `ObservableList` in the ListView, so I modified it. I also thought having a cleaner lambda example would be good.

Comment: Thanks for this input. However my problem was to pass property name as a string not as a direct call to the method. Also your code has diferent behaviour than PropertyValueFactory for table where we can use simple getter. Taking Java 8 approach probably static reference would be acceptable as a parameter instead of string.